# Displaying a google maps that shows the chosen address

Tags: jquery, api, google-maps

Ok so the user chooses the country, then via autocomplete widgets they get to choose the district, city and area they live in. The the values they've chosen are concatenated into an address which should be used to call the Google Maps API and display a Map that marks the address... Unfortunately, this is not working... I am getting this exception in Firebug:

> uncaught exception: [Exception...
>   "Component returned failure code:
>   0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE)
>   [nsIDOMViewCSS.getComputedStyle]"
>   nsresult: "0x80004005
>   (NS_ERROR_FAILURE)" location: "JS
>   frame ::
>   http://maps.gstatic.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/api-3/4/11a/main.js
>   :: Xk :: line 55" data: no]

Here's my code:

a script tag with this `src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"`

```
var address = selectedArea + ', ' + selectedCity + ', ' + selectedDistrict + ', Lebanon';

var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address }, function (results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        var map = new google.maps.Map($("#addressMap"));
        map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: results[0].geometry.location
        });
    } else {
        alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
    }
});
```

So what's going on?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

When you create the map object you give a jQuery object but it excepts a DOM object. Try DOM object itself.

I added some options also, zoom level and map type.

Here is the final code:

```
var address = selectedArea + ', ' + selectedCity + ', ' + selectedDistrict + ', Lebanon';

var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address }, function (results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        var mapOptions = { zoom: 8, mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('addressMap'), mapOptions);
        map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: results[0].geometry.location
        });
    } else {
        alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
    }
});
```

Comment: Perfect! Worked exactly the way I wanted! Thank you :)

Comment: I was under the impression that document.getElementById('addressMap') was equivalent to $('div#addressMap'). Clearly not. Thanks for helping me.

Comment: @AdamWaite `document.getElementById()` returns a DOM object, `$()` returns a jQuery object.

Comment: you can always do .get(0) on a jQuery object to get the (first) DOM element.